# Number of flops required to invert a matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, computational-complexity

I have an n-by-n upper triangular matrix $R$ and I can calculate its inverse by back substitution. I cannot make myself see why it needs $O(n^{3}/3)$ flops to do so. Can you explain?

Comment: Why is it $O(n^3/3)$? We normally simply write $O(n^3)$.

Comment: I'm quoting from the book "Matrix Computations" by Golub. But either way, why?

Comment: See if you can understand it from here, it's quite well-explained: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Jordan_elimination#Computational_efficiency

Answer (score 7):

Why matrix inversion by Jordan-Gauss elimination scales as $O(n^3)$ is quite well-explained [here on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Jordan_elimination#Computational_efficiency); see if you can understand it from there - I doubt I could do better myself.

Now about your $O(n^3/3)$: note that it takes approximately $2n^3/3$ operations to invert a generic matrix. For a triangular matrix, it takes half the number of operations, hence the $n^3/3$ in your book.

A final note: while saying that something takes $kn^3$ operations is fine, writing $O(n^3/3)$ is quite strange. This is because the big-O notation was introduced precisely  to do away with having to specify constants, since complexity theory is mainly concerned with how algorithms *scale*. In practice, of course, knowing the constant can be very important (compare $2^n$ with $1000n$ for $n=3$, say); I'm just saying that the *notation* is strange.

Comment: @ MGA  , for a generic matrix, $2/3n^3$ is the complexity of LU decomposition; the complexity of inversion is $n^3$.