# Counting the number of operations in solving $Ax = b$ for a 2x2 matrix $A$

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

I have been tasked with showing that the number of operations needed to solve $Ax = b$ for a tridiagonal n x n matrix $A$ is $8(n-1)+1$. I tried to solve this and I was getting too large an answer, so I realised there must be a flaw in the way I am counting. I decided to simply the problem and try to count the operations the case $n=2$.

By the formula, there should be nine operations, but as far as I can tell the minimum amount needed is ten. Say we have

$a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2=b_1$ and

$a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2=b_2$.

I count that you would need 6 operations to do Gauss-Jordan elimination to get an upper triangular matrix:

$a_{21} \rightarrow 0$ (no operations), $a_{22} \rightarrow a_{22}-(\frac{a_{21}}{a_{11}}) a_{12}$ (3 operations) and $b_2 \rightarrow b_2-(\frac{a_{21}}{a_{11}}) b_1$ (3 operations)

and a further four to do back substitution:

$x_2 = \frac{b_2}{a_{22}}$ (1 operation) and $x_1 = \frac{b_1-a_{12}x_2}{a_{11}}$ (3 operations).

If someone could say where my logic is wrong that would be great.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I decided to remove the answer since it did not add value. Now, as per your question, using the inverse method you still get the same order (see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742228/number-of-flops-required-to-invert-a-matrix). The following link gives more details about the number of operations using Gauss: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/counting-operations-in-gaussian-elimination and it is not 8(N-1)+1.

Comment: The division $a_{21}/a_{11}$ gets done twice. If this were computing an in-place LU decomposition, that factor would be stored in $a_{21}$. This would then give: $a_{21}\rightarrow a_{21}/a_{11}$. The other two updates in the factorisation step are $a_{22}\rightarrow a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12}$ and $b\rightarrow b_2-a_{21}b_1$. This gives 5 operations for the factorisation, compared to your 6.